# Loop through all inputs in a div with a certain class

Tags: jquery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.js"></script>

<script>

    $('.disabledForm').each(function(i, div) {
    alert('in here');
    $(div).find('input').each(function(j, element){
        $(element).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
    });
</script>

<div id="divDisabled" class="disabledForm">
            <label>Disabled Input 1&nbsp;<input type="text" id="disabledInput1" name="disabledInput1" /></label>
            <br />
            <label>Disabled Input 2&nbsp;<input type="text" id="disabledInput2" name="disabledInput2" /></label>
        </div>
```

Never see the "in here" message and my Inputs never get disabled so I assume I'm doing something wrong. Can someone tell me what it is I'm not doing right?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/prop to disable form elements.

Comment: I also recommend using a newer version of jQuery than 1.6.

Comment: you also don't need to use .each so much. `$(this).find('input').prop('disabled',true);` is just fine, and won't eat up resources like `.each` will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap you code in a `$(function(){ ... })` block, in order to let it see the whole DOM.

```
<script>
$(function(){ 

    //your js code here

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.disabledForm').each(function(i, div) {
        alert('in here');
        $(div).find('input').each(function(j, element)
        {
            $(element).attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your function around $(document).ready(function() { 'Your method in here' }.